# firestore security rules - how to print out the rule values?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How do we check what the values are in firebase security rules? I have some rules that are failing but they shouldn't be so I need to check what is actually happening in there. Is there a console.log() or console.print() ability?

```
match /test/{testId} {
  //console.log(resource.data.relationships.keys());
  allow read: if resource.data.relationships.keys().hasAll([request.auth.uid]);
  allow write: if userIsAuthenticated();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the Firestore emulator, what you're looking for is the [`debug` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.debug), which:

1. Logs the value passed in, and then
2. Returns that value

Note:

> `debug` function blocks are only executed by the Security Rules engine in the Firestore emulator, part of the Firebase Emulator Suite. The `debug` function has no effect in production.

You can use it anywhere in your rule value, so all of these are valid:

- `if debug(resource.data.relationships.keys().hasAll([request.auth.uid]))`
- `if resource.data.relationships.keys().hasAll([debug(request.auth.uid)])`

I'm curious if this is also valid:

- `if debug(resource.data.relationships.keys()).hasAll([request.auth.uid])`

Let me know if you've given that a try.